# How can I get SEs from predict(glmmLasso )

Tags: glmmlasso

I am using glmmLasso in R to get predictions; my outcome is binary so I am using a logit model. My code looks something like this:

```
glm.fit<-glmmLasso(y~ x1 +.. xn, rnd=list(id=~1),
           lambda=1,family=binomial(link=logit),switch.NR=TRUE, final.re=FALSE)
```

After which I would like to get the predicted outcome and SE of the prediction. I can do this

```
prob<-predict(glm.fit)
```

to get predicted probabilities, but I'd like to also have the linear predictions, xb, and the standard error of this prediction, stdxb, for each observation.

I've tried

```
se<-predict(glm.fit, se.fit=TRUE)
```

but this seems to ignore the se.fit option and return the same probabilities as the earlier code. Is it possible to get some estimate of precision for the predicted values?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Your model is called `glm.fit` and not just `glm`. Your code might run better if you update this possible error in your code (though I have my doubts it would even run at all, so I suspect this is just an oversight in the post here). // I didn't think LASSO standard errors were settled to the extent that they are settled for maximum likelihood estimation of logistic regression (it isn't even *settled* settled for maximum likelihood, but at least we have Wald, likelihood ratio, and score tests). What does the package documentation say that `se.fit` argument does?

Comment: Thanks for noting the typo, which I fixed. The documentation for -glmmLasso- only says that "The predict function returns predictions on the scale of the response variable and uses also estimates of random effects for prediction, if possible (i.e. for known subjects of the grouping factor)."  So maybe that's all I can get.